# Parsing through python using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to parse through the poorly structured website of a restaurant and print out just the menu headers like:

"Bento Box",
"Bara Chirashi set",
etc

I'm using the Python library Beautiful Soup, but I'm having trouble getting the proper output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('http://www.sushitaro.com/menu-lunch.html')
r = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'pass'))

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
dataList = list()

for string in soup.findAll('b'):
    dataList.append(string)

print(dataList)
```

This returns too many elements, they are returned as HTML not just text, and the textual contents themselves are really messy with unicode characters and excess whitespace.

I'm really having trouble with this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "having trouble" mean? What does this do wrong? It looks like you're trying to select all bolded text; does it not do that, or does it do that, but that isn't what you actually wanted to do?

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble with this page, as it is so badly formatted. Also you don't need the auth=(...) part of your coe, as no authorisation is needed to access this page ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to get the names of menu items from the website in question.  Page scraping can be tricky and, more than learning the library, you have to look at the structure of the page.  Here, for example, prices are also bold so if you just want the names of the menu items you have to find a different distinguishing feature.  In this case, the site designer has incremented the font size by one for each menu title so, following your code through the definition of "soup", you can grab all and only the menu titles with:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = ('http://www.sushitaro.com/menu-lunch.html')
r = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'pass'))
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

menuTitlesHTML = soup.findAll('font', {"size": "+1"})
```

Now, this will return a lot of HTML and not just the text. I assume you are familiar with Python list comprehensions which are really handy here. If you want the text you can try instead:

```
menuTitlesDirty = [titleHTML.text for titleHTML in menuTitlesHTML]
```

But now you'll notice that the titles have a lot of excess whitespace, including in unicode, and some extra characters like '@s.' Since you seem to only want the ASCII menu titles we can simply convert to ASCII, ignoring errors, to clean the unicode.  To this we can substitute a single space for matches on a regular expression that captures the undesired characters: newline characters, spaces and @s. To this we can apply ".strip()", removing extra spaces at the end of our strings. In sum this is:

```
import re
badChars = re.compile('[\s@]+')
menuTitles = [badChars.sub(" ", dirtyTitle.encode('ascii', 'ignore')).strip() for dirtyTitle in menuTitlesDirty]
```

This returns what you suggested you wanted:

```
['Lunch Bento Box',
 'Bara Chirashi set',
 'Tekka Chirashi set',
 'Sushi Mori set',
 'Sushi Jo set',
 'Sushi Tokujo set',
 'Sashimi & Tempura Teishoku',
 'Tokujo Sashimi',
 "Today's Lunch Special",
 'Saba Shioyaki Teishoku',
 'Katsu Don set',
 'Tem Don set',
 'Cold Soba or Udon w/one topping',
 'Hot Soup Udon or Soba w/one Topping']
```

To sum up: page scraping is a messy and iterative process where you want to use any discrepancy on the page to your advantage. The Python REPL is really your friend, here. Hopefully this gives you and others an idea of many tools, in Python more generally and Beautiful Soup in particular, that can help with this process.

Comment: Thanks you so much but I'm getting a 
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I took out the .text.encoding('ascii', 'ignore') and everything is fine except the first element is '                            lunch bento box            '

Comment: Apologies: I've now added the part of your code, @WakkaDroid, that was necessary to my own and corrected one mistake: .encoding(...) is necessary but the preceding .text was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output may just be illegible because of the way you print it.

Try:

```
for d in dataList:
    print(d)
```